# Using scipy.optimize.curve_fit within a class

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, class-method

I have a class describing a mathematical function.  The class needs to be able to least squares fit itself to passed in data.  i.e. you can call a method like this:

```
classinstance.Fit(x,y)
```

and it adjusts its internal variables to best fit the data.  I'm trying to use scipy.optimize.curve_fit for this, and it needs me to pass in a model function.  The problem is that the model function is within the class and needs to access the variables and members of the class to compute the data.  However, curve_fit can't call a function whose first parameter is self.  Is there a way to make curve_fit use a method of the class as it's model function?

Here is a minimum executable snippet to show the issue:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# This is a class which encapsulates a gaussian and fits itself to data.
class GaussianComponent():
    # This is a formula string showing the exact code used to produce the gaussian.  I
    # It has to be printed for the user, and it can be used to compute values.
    Formula = 'self.Amp*np.exp(-((x-self.Center)**2/(self.FWHM**2*np.sqrt(2))))'

    # These parameters describe the gaussian.
    Center = 0
    Amp = 1
    FWHM = 1

    # HERE IS THE CONUNDRUM: IF I LEAVE SELF IN THE DECLARATION, CURVE_FIT
    # CANNOT CALL IT SINCE IT REQUIRES THE WRONG NUMBER OF PARAMETERS.
    # IF I REMOVE IT, FITFUNC CAN'T ACCESS THE CLASS VARIABLES.
    def FitFunc(self, x, y, Center, Amp, FWHM):
        eval('y - ' + self.Formula.replace('self.', ''))

    # This uses curve_fit to adjust the gaussian parameters to best match the
    # data passed in.
    def Fit(self, x, y):
        #FitFunc = lambda x, y, Center, Amp, FWHM: eval('y - ' + self.Formula.replace('self.', ''))
        FitParams, FitCov = curve_fit(self.FitFunc, x, y, (self.Center, self.Amp, self.FWHM))
        self.Center = FitParams[0]
        self.Amp = FitParams[1]
        self.FWHM = FitParams[2]

    # Give back a vector which describes what this gaussian looks like.
    def GetPlot(self, x):
        y = eval(self.Formula)
        return y

# Make a gausssian with default shape and position (height 1 at the origin, FWHM 1.
g = GaussianComponent()

# Make a space in which we can plot the gaussian.
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y = g.GetPlot(x)

# Make some "experimental data" which is just the default shape, noisy, and
# moved up the y axis a tad so the best fit will be different.
ynoise = y + np.random.normal(loc=0.1, scale=0.1, size=len(x))

# Draw it
plt.plot(x,y, x,ynoise)
plt.show()

# Do the fit (but this doesn't work...)
g.Fit(x,y)
```

And this produces the following graph and then crashes since the model function is incorrect when it tries to do the fit.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I spent some time looking at your code and turned out 2 minutes late unfortunately. Anyhow, to make things a bit more interesting I've edited your class a bit, Here's what I concocted:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

class GaussianComponent():

    def __init__(self, func, params=None):
        self.formula = func
        self.params = params

    def eval(self, x):
        allowed_locals = {key: self.params[key] for key in self.params}
        allowed_locals["x"] = x
        allowed_globals = {"np":np}
        return eval(self.formula, allowed_globals, allowed_locals)

    def Fit(self, x, y):
        FitParams, FitCov = curve_fit(self.eval, x, y, self.params)
        self.fitparams = fitParams


# Make a gausssian with default shape and position (height 1 at the origin, FWHM 1.
g = GaussianComponent("Amp*np.exp(-((x-Center)**2/(FWHM**2*np.sqrt(2))))", 
                      params={"Amp":1, "Center":0, "FWHM":1})

**SNIPPED FOR BREVITY**
```

I believe you'll perhaps find this a more satisfying solution?

Currently all your gauss parameters are class attributes, that means if you try to create a second instance of your class with different values for parameters you will change the values for the first class too. By shoving all the parameters as instance attribute(s), you get rid of that. That is why we have classes in the first place.

Your issue with `self` stems from the fact you write `self` in your `Formula`. Now you don't have to any more. I think it makes a bit more sense like this, because when you instantiate an object of the class you can add as many or as little params to your declared function as you want. It doesn't even have to be gaussian now (unlike before).

Just throw all params to a dictionary, just like `curve_fit` does and forget about them.

By explicitly stating what `eval` can use, you help make sure that any evil-doers have a harder time breaking your code. It's still possible though, it always is with `eval`.

Good luck, ask if you need something clarified.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh!  It was actually a bug in my code.  If I change this line:

```
def FitFunc(self, x, y, Center, Amp, FWHM):
```

to

```
def FitFunc(self, x, Center, Amp, FWHM):
```

Then we are fine.  So curve_fit does correctly handle the self parameter but my model function shouldn't include y.

(Embarrased!)

Comment: for me [there is no clue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L454) that `curve_fit` is properly handling that...